# I have an Asp.net mvc project with Individual User Accounts. I want each user just see own data created before in index method in controller

Tags: asp.net

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private PurcasementEntities db = new PurcasementEntities();

    // GET: Order
    public ActionResult Index(string Dep, string searchString)
    {
        var DepLst = new List<string>();
        var DepQry = from d in db.Orders
                     orderby d.Department
                     select d.Department;
        DepLst.AddRange(DepQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.Dep = new SelectList(DepLst);

        var ord = from m in db.Orders
                  select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            ord = ord.Where(s => s.Description.Contains(searchString));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dep))
        {
            ord = ord.Where(x => x.Department == Dep);
        }

        return View(ord);
    }
}
```

Comment: What  is exactlly the problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

For login what kind of authentication you are using?
Hope it's identity server. 
Then you can get the logged in user ID by the code '''User.Identity.Name'''. Just filter your database record by using the where clause in your query like "'where userID = User.Identity.Name"'

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not important that i have tow db context 
one of them is ApplicationDBcontext 
and the other have named " PurccasementEntiteies"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.